# Clearance additional strong_parameters in RoR4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, clearance

I am using the clearance gem, which is basically an authentication by e-mail.

Now I want to keep the log in via email, but want to add a 'name' field into the registration form for the user.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Clearance::User

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController
  def create
    @user = user_from_params

    if @user.save(permit_params)
      sign_in @user
      render :json => {:success => true}
    else
      render :json => {:success => false}
    end
  end

  private

  def user_from_params
    user_params = params[:user] || Hash.new
    email = user_params.delete(:email)
    password = user_params.delete(:password)

    Clearance.configuration.user_model.new(user_params).tap do |user|
      user.email = email
      user.password = password
    end
  end

  def permit_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :encrypted_password, :password, :confirmation_token, :remember_token)
  end
end
```

As you can see I added the permission to `.save` and still the app throws me the following error upon request:

`ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Clearance::UsersController#create`

If I remove the `:name` text field from my form everything works, but I want additional fields for my form.

Comment: I'm not seeing what is wrong within what you have shown.  Can you show db/schema.rb?  Have you migrated the :name column into the database?

Comment: Should the `permit_params` not be in the `.new(...)` statement, e.g. `Clearance.configuration.user_model.new(permit_params).tap...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your **users_controller** into folders like this:

**app/controllers/clearance/users_controller.rb**

Then in **users_controller.rb**, instead of:

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController
```

you need to put:

```
class Clearance::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

This doesn't override the Clearance User Controller. Instead, now you are writing it. This is the controller that your sign-up form will go to. Thus, you still need to include the base code from Clearance's gem and edit 
**Clearance::UsersController#user_from_params**

```
def user_from_params
  user_params = params[:user] || Hash.new
  email = user_params.delete(:email)
  password = user_params.delete(:password)
  name = user_params.delete(:name)

  Clearance.configuration.user_model.new(user_params).tap do |user|
    user.email = email
    user.password = password
    user.name = name
  end
end
```

and update **Clearance::UsersController#permit_params**

```
def permit_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: I've changed my previous answer since it was missing the point.

The code you've provided is fine. The reason you're getting `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is because you're not overriding the Clearance Users Controller.

You need to tell your app to use your overriding controller instead of the controller inside Clearance's engine, by adding the following to your config/routes.rb.

```
resources :users,
  controller: 'users',
  only: 'create'
```

IMO this is better than writing a new `Clearance::UsersController` in your application code above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both ways and came to the realization that you don't need the permit params. You only need to do 4 things:

- Add a name column in the migration
- Create **app/controllers/users_contoller.rb** to override gem controller
- Create the new form to accept name **app/views/users/new.html.erb**
- Modify your routes

Starting from the generated migration `rails generate clearance:install` (before running `rake db:migrate`)

1. add a `name:string` column with an index such so that your migration looks like:
   by adding this column, it is included in the creation of the user params.

   ```
   def change
     change_table :users do |t|
       t.timestamps null: false
       t.string :email, null: false
       t.string :name, null: false, limit: 50
       t.string :encrypted_password, limit: 128, null: false
       t.string :confirmation_token, limit: 128
       t.string :remember_token, limit: 128, null: false
     end

     add_index :users, :name
     add_index :users, :email
     add_index :users, :remember_token
   end
   ```

Then you only need to create 2 files:

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController

  def create
    @user = user_from_params

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render template: 'users/new'
    end 
  end 

  private

  def user_from_params
    user_params = params[:user] || Hash.new
    name = user_params.delete(:name)
    email = user_params.delete(:email)
    password = user_params.delete(:password)

    Clearance.configuration.user_model.new(user_params).tap do |user|
      user.name = name
      user.email = email
      user.password = password
    end
  end
end
```

and

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<div id='clearance' class='sign-up'>
  <h2><%= t('.title') %></h2>

  <%= form_for @user do |form| %>
  <div class='text-field'>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, :type => 'name' %>
  </div>

  <div class='text-field'>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, :type => 'email' %>
  </div>

  <div class='password-field'>
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class='submit-field'>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

  <div class='other-links'>
    <%= link_to t('.sign_in'), sign_in_path %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then your routes should include this

```
resources :users,
    controller: 'users',
    only: 'create'
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to reimplement `create` method, just in case if you're creating an API (what looks like).

The steps are:

- config/routes.rb

  ```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users, controller: 'users', only: Clearance.configuration.user_actions
  end
  ```
- app/controllers/users_controller.rb

  ```
  class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController

    private

    def user_from_params
      email = user_params.delete(:email)
      password = user_params.delete(:password)
      name = user_params.delete(:name)

      Clearance.configuration.user_model.new(user_params).tap do |user|
        user.email = email
        user.password = password
        user.name = name
      end
    end

  end
  ```

After that, add the name field into your form and it's done.